# Git help: Find a missing branch/ missing commit

Tags: git, github, version-control

Basically, I made a bunch of commits to a branch I can't seem to find. When I then pulled from my remote branch, I lost these changes. Is there someway I can see a comprehensive list of all commits I've made on my computer using git, or any branches I've committed to using git? I know for sure the commits were made (I don't think I managed to push them), I just can't figure out where they're hiding... I tried `git branch` but didn't see my mysterious mystery branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git reflog` is your friend. It will show you all your "recent" (and not so recent) commits, merges, cherry-picks, checkouts.